# Reusing sprites when using a lot of them

Tags: objective-c, ios6, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, sprite

I am in front of a problem when adding sprites on my game layer.

When the game starts it's initialize a two dimensional array (that I created) and put 30 sprites in it (5 columns, 6 lines). It's always the same image that I use for the 30 sprites.

The problem is that each time I create a new sprite...

Every 3 sec all sprites deseaper and new ones appear. I am using ARC but when I check into Instruments (allocations part) I can see the number of living sprites increasing every 3sec 30, 60, 90, 120 ...

So when I play for 15 minutes my game crash. How can I use the same sprite without creating a new one ?

I tried to create it in the init method but then when I enter in [self addChild : mysprite] it says to me that the sprite had already been add.

Here is my code :

```
int yValue = 400;
    for (int line = 0; line < nbLines; line++) {
        int xValue = 32;
        for (int section = 0; section < nbSection ; section++) {
            MySprite *mySprite = [[MySprite alloc] initWithFile:@"mySprite.png"];
            mySprite.position = ccp(xValue, yValue);
            [gameTab setObject:mySprite :section :line];
            [self addChild:mySprite];
            xValue += 64;
        }
        yValue -= 64;
    }
```

and here is what I do for deleting the sprite :

```
[gameTab removeChild:mySprite cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:mySprite cleanup:YES];
```

I don't know when ARC deallocate my sprites.

Thx.

Comment: When are you calling your sprite creation code? What is gameTab? You aren't giving enough information.

Comment: I create my sprite every 3 secunds and gameTab is a two dimensions array that I created to stock all my sprites. Sorry about that.

Comment: When are you deleting the sprites? If every sprite has the same image, you should look into using a batchNode.

Comment: ARC deallocates sprites virtually immediately they are no longer referenced. See it this way: With ARC, the compiler generates the `retain` `release` ... for you at about the same place you would (when doing it in an efficient way).  The fact that your app crashes, and that you see memory usage increase, means that there is an issue with your code: It maintains references to the old sprites.

Comment: @Smugbit Studioa -> I delete all sprites every 3 sec. Yeah I will implement the loading of my sprites with batchNode for sure.

Comment: @meangin-matters  thx but if ARC deallocates sprites virtually how can I tell him to deallocate the old sprites ?